# How to create child class instance using some magic in parent __new__?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, python-3.x, instance

For example, creating custom number types in following hierarchy

- `Number`

  - `Complex`
  - `Real`

    - `Int`
    - `Float`

with logic in `__new__` methods:

```
class Number:
    def __new__(cls, value):
        if isinstance(value, complex):
            return Complex(value)
        elif isinstance(value, (int, float)):
            return Real(value)
        else:
            raise TypeError('Ну ты и мудак!!!')

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value


class Complex(Number):
    pass


class Real(Number):
    def __new__(cls, value):
        if isinstance(value, int):
            return Int(value)
        elif isinstance(value, float):
            return Float(value)
        else:
            raise TypeError('Ты больше не можешь вести себя так!!!')


class Int(Real):
    pass


class Float(Real):
    pass
```

And then, creating `Float` instance using `Number` constructor:

```
number = Number(6.6)
assert isinstance(number, Float)
```

This code will raise `RuntimeError` because of recursion limit. It is just example of desired behaviour. But I also tried to implement this using `super` and it is seems I misunderstand the world.

Comment: No need to use `@staticmethod` on `__new__`; Python treats it as a static method regardless, not in the least because there is no class or instance to bind to *anyway*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Complex`, `Float` and `Int` classes do *not* have `__new__` methods, so they inherit these from `Number`; this is what is causing your infinite recursion.

You could test against the `__class__` closure to see if you have a subclass or not:

```
class Number:
    def __new__(cls, value):
        if cls is not __class__:
            # Subclass, create an instance (invokes object.__new__)
            return super().__new__(cls)

        if isinstance(value, complex):
            return Complex(value)
        elif isinstance(value, (int, float)):
            return Real(value)
        else:
            raise TypeError('Ну ты и мудак!!!')

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
```

and do the same in `Real`:

```
class Real(Number):
    def __new__(cls, value):
        if cls is not __class__:
            # Subclass, create an instance
            return super().__new__(cls, value)

        if isinstance(value, int):
            return Int(value)
        elif isinstance(value, float):
            return Float(value)
        else:
            raise TypeError('Ты больше не можешь вести себя так!!!')
```

Demo:

```
>>> class Number:
...     def __new__(cls, value):
...         if cls is not __class__:
...             # Subclass, create an instance
...             return super().__new__(cls)
...         if isinstance(value, complex):
...             return Complex(value)
...         elif isinstance(value, (int, float)):
...             return Real(value)
...         else:
...             raise TypeError('Ну ты и мудак!!!')
...     def __init__(self, value):
...         self.value = value
... 
>>> class Real(Number):
...     def __new__(cls, value):
...         if cls is not __class__:
...             # Subclass, create an instance
...             return super().__new__(cls, value)
...         if isinstance(value, int):
...             return Int(value)
...         elif isinstance(value, float):
...             return Float(value)
...         else:
...             raise TypeError('Ты больше не можешь вести себя так!!!')
... 
>>> class Complex(Number):
...     pass
... 
>>> class Int(Real):
...     pass
... 
>>> class Float(Real):
...     pass
... 
>>> number = Number(6.6)
>>> isinstance(number, Float)
True
```