# Have a class to initialise an object from a different class

Tags: python, class, inheritance, polymorphism, factory-method

Currently, I have a `@classmethod` that returns the right class given a variable. It looks something like:

```
class Parent():
  @classmethod
  def GetInstance(cls, variable):
    if variable == 'foo':
      return Child()


class Child(Parent):
  def Something(self):
    pass

instance = Parent.GetInstance('foo')
result = instance.Something()
```

I prefer not to define and use `GetInstance`. Instead, I would like the `Main()` to simply be:

```
instance = Parent('foo')
result = instance.Something()
```

While keeping all the benefits of the structure above. I want class `Parent()` to return an object of class `Child()` when called, without the need of using a method. `__init__` unfortunately does not seem to help, as it cannot return anything. Any ideas?

Comment: You can use `__new__`, but in many cases you're better off just writing a factory function.

Comment: Yeah, Python's class model does not easily support this. I can't think of a way, because, as you have found out, `__init__` does not like to `return` things. Just use the factory pattern... this is well known.

Comment: @BrenBarn Yeah, I suppose you could use `__new__`. This would be a totally over-engineered solution to a non-problem. This would be totally surprising to anyone using your `class`.

Comment: I actually tried using __new__ and did not work. Maybe I did something wring, feel free to suggest actual implementation.

Comment: If using `__new__` didn't work, then you didn't do it correctly. You should share that code.

Answer (score 0):

Just override '**new**' special  method. It's '**new**' method which is responsible for calling creating an instance, allocating memory and then initialize it by calling '**init**' . To be specific

> **new** is static class method, while **init** is instance method. **new** has to create the instance first, so **init** can initialize it. Note that **init** takes self as parameter. Until you create instance there is no self.

Comment: Looks to me that a problem is that you will get the call back: the `__new__` calls `Child()`, child calls the `Child`s `__new__` that will call the `Parent`s `__new__` and thus you will receive the call twice.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** Ok, I went back and fixed it. Totally hackey and very brittle. I hope you don't want to keep extending this. I put this here as illustrative of *why* this is a bad idea.

Here is a sketch of how you **could** accomplish this. But please, *just use a factory method*.

```
>>> class Parent(object):
...     def __new__(typ, *args, **kwargs):
...         if args and args[0] == 'foo':
...             return Child()
...         else:
...             return super(Parent, typ).__new__(typ)
...
>>> class Child(Parent):
...     __new__ = object.__new__
...
>>> a = Parent('foo')
>>> a
<__main__.Child object at 0x1023275f8>
>>> p = Parent()
>>> p
<__main__.Parent object at 0x1023275c0>
>>>
```

Comment: They wish to have `Child` as a child of `Parent`, which is where I assume the difficulties with `__new__` came from.

Comment: @KevinMGranger crap, my mistake. Yeah, this gets messy quick. Gimme a sec...

Comment: @KevinMGranger Ok, I've got a working skeleton now, brittle as all hell.

Comment: The "right" way to do it is here: [In python 3, how to create child class instance using some magic in parent __new__?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26524065/in-python-3-how-to-create-child-class-instance-using-some-magic-in-parent-new)

Comment: Ah yes, as always, @MartijnPieters demonstrates the elegant way of doing things.

Answer (score -1):

Add a list of children[] in your parent class:

```
class Parent():
    def __init__(self):
        children = list()
```

That way you can create a child() object and then append it by doing:

```
child - Child()  # create new child obj
parent.children.append(child)
```

Then it should be simple to get a child from the list of children that you want using a loop etc.

Comment: The objective is not to create a list of children, but to pass a parameter and in case the parameter of `'foo'`, construct a child instead.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem why don't you just post an answer?

Comment: I did until I realized that the answer was not that trivial. Once you have admin rights, you can even see that answer ;).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yeah, I couldn't help but try. It's stupid and a good exercise to show why you should just use a factory method. It's almost as if this were some sort of *pattern* that *other software developers* had come up with to make their lives easier...