# Instantiate a child in __new__ with different __new__ signature for a child

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance

## Preface

I want to have 2 classes `Interval` and `Segment` with the following  properties:

1. `Interval` can have `start` & `end` points, any of them can be included/excluded (I've implemented this using required flag parameters like `start_inclusive`/`end_inclusive`).
2. `Segment` is an `Interval` with both endpoints included, so user do not need to specify those flags.
3. If user is trying to create `Interval` with endpoints included he gets a `Segment` like

   ```
   >>> Interval(0, 1, start_inclusive=True, end_inclusive=True)
   Segment(0, 1)
   ```

   ([this doesn't look impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26524065/in-python-3-how-to-create-child-class-instance-using-some-magic-in-parent-new))

## Problem

My [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) implementation so far is

`Interval` class:

```
class Interval:
    def __new__(cls, start: int, end: int,
                *,
                start_inclusive: bool,
                end_inclusive: bool) -> 'Interval':
        if cls is not __class__:
            return super().__new__(cls)
        if start == end:
            raise ValueError('Degenerate interval found.')
        if start_inclusive and end_inclusive:
            return Segment(start, end)
        return super().__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self,
                 start: int,
                 end: int,
                 *,
                 start_inclusive: bool,
                 end_inclusive: bool) -> None:
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        self.start_inclusive = start_inclusive
        self.end_inclusive = end_inclusive
```

`Segment` class:

```
class Segment(Interval):
    def __new__(cls, start: int, end: int) -> 'Interval':
        return super().__new__(cls, start, end,
                               start_inclusive=True,
                               end_inclusive=True)

    def __init__(self, start: int, end: int) -> None:
        super().__init__(start, end,
                         start_inclusive=True,
                         end_inclusive=True)
```

Creation kinda works

```
>>> Interval(0, 1, start_inclusive=False, end_inclusive=True)
<__main__.Interval object at ...>
>>> Interval(0, 1, start_inclusive=False, end_inclusive=False)
<__main__.Interval object at ...>
>>> Segment(0, 1)
<__main__.Segment object at ...>
```

but

```
>>> Interval(0, 1, start_inclusive=True, end_inclusive=True)
```

fails with following `TypeError`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'end_inclusive'
```

So my question is:

**Is there any idiomatic way of instantiating child class in parent's `__new__` with some parameters of `__new__` & `__init__` "bound" by a child?**

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want the user to just pick what class they want? Also, is there any special functionality you get in a segment that an interval does not have?

Comment: @MadPhysicist: yes to both questions, checking if point is in segment will be faster (I've measured it, and yes, this small improvement does matter due to number of checks and intervals) because I don't need to find out which operator `<` or `<=` to use while checking endpoints, because it will be `<=`, but the problem is more general from my perspective

Comment: Segment and Interval seem quite different ideas, even if they have common functionality. If they could maybe share a common abstract base class, instead of being in line in a hierarchy, both the ideas would be better expressed, and your instantiation made simpler?

Comment: @ReblochonMasque. I was going to suggest a factory regardless. But this question has intrinsic interest, outside of design implications.

Comment: @AzatIbrakov. Could you show the full traceback for that error?

Comment: @MadPhysicist: it is a full traceback from REPL

Comment: @ReblochonMasque: I can call them `Segment` and `ClosedSegment` if it helps, but the problem is not with particular classes, but with a possibility of creating child class in parent based on parameters analysis

Comment: This design looks very fishy to me. What exactly are you trying to do with the `if cls is not __class__:` part of the code?

Comment: @wim: as I understood it helps to avoid infinite recursion, got it from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26524734/5997596)

Comment: @wim. I had the same thought. It avoids getting to the line `if start_inclusive and end_inclusive:` for a `Segment`, which would set up an infinite loop.

Comment: I understand @AzatIbrakov

Comment: I think I figured out what is happening, and the only answer I can think of is to override `__call__` in the metaclass to check identity of classes instead of allowing subclasses.

Comment: Basically, when `__new__` returns a `Segment`, `Segment` is still a subclass of `Interval`, so it attempts to call `type(obj).__init__(obj)` on the result. But `obj` is missing the two keyword parameters in its `__init__`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at why you get the error first. When you call a class derived from [`object`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#object), the [`__call__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__) method of the [metaclass](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#metaclasses) ([`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type)) is called. That usually goes something like

```
self = cls.__new__(...)
if isinstance(self, cls):
    type(self).__init__(self)
```

This is only approximate, but enough to convey what is happening here:

1. `type.__call__` calls [`Interval.__new__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__)
2. Since `start_inclusive and end_inclusive`, `Interval.__new__` correctly returns an instance of `Segment`
3. Since `issubclass(Segment, Interval)`, `type.__call__` calls `Segment.__init__` with all the parameters that you had passed to the call to `Interval`
4. `Segment.__init__` does not accept any keyword parameters, and raises the error you see.

There are a number of workarounds to this situation. [@jdehesa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57079855/2988730) shows how to override the behavior of `type` so that `type.__call__` checks `type(obj) is cls` instead of using `isinstance`.

Another alternative would be to dissociate the hierarchy of `Interval` and `Segment`. You could do something like

```
class MyBase:
    # put common functionality here

class Interval(MyBase):
    # __new__ and __init__ same as before

class Segment(MyBase):
    # __new__ and __init__ same as before
```

With this arrangement `isinstance(Segment(...), Interval)` will be `False`, and `type.__call__` will *not* attempt to call `Interval.__init__` on a `Segment`.

The simplest way to do this, in my opinion, would be to use a factory pattern. Have an external function  that determines what type of object to return based on the input. That way, you do not need to implement `__new__` at all, and your class construction process will be much simpler:

```
def factory(start, end, *, start_inclusive, end_inclusive):
    if start_inclusive and end_inclusive:
        return Segment(start, end)
    return Interval(start, end, start_inclusive=start_inclusive, end_inclusive=end_inclusive)
```

Comment: I think the question is interesting on itself, but yes, I would definitely go with a factory for this, call it `interval` (lowercase). Would be good if you could somehow made the constructors of the actual classes "private" so you don't make the mistake of calling the constructor directly, but I'm not sure there is any reasonable way of doing that in Python (since I don't consider inspecting the stack trace from the constructor to emulate C++ `friend` behavior "reasonable").

Comment: @jdehesa. I've found that good documentation and consenting adults usually ends up solving the issues other languages use privacy for. As I told OP before, I don't like restricting options, even if I don't end up using them. One day, I may want to explicitly make an `Interval` with both endpoints inclusive.

Comment: I've ended up using factories (and delegating all validation to them) and considering such tricky `__new__` behavior a hack, which can be enforced using metaclasses and I don't really need them, at least in current state

Comment: @AzatIbrakov. I'm glad you went with the sensible solution. Why make your code unmaintainable when you don't have to?

Answer (score 2):

You can solve that with a metaclass to customize when `__init__` is called after `__new__`:

```
class IntervalMeta(type):
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = cls.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        # Only call __init__ if class of object is exactly this class
        if type(obj) is cls:
            cls.__init__(obj, *args, **kwargs)
        # As opposed to default behaviour:
        # if isinstance(obj, cls):
        #     type(obj).__init__(obj, *args, **kwargs)
        return obj

# Code below does not change except for metaclass
class Interval(metaclass=IntervalMeta):
    def __new__(cls, start: int, end: int,
                *,
                start_inclusive: bool,
                end_inclusive: bool) -> 'Interval':
        if cls is not __class__:
            return super().__new__(cls)
        if start == end:
            raise ValueError('Degenerate interval found.')
        if start_inclusive and end_inclusive:
            return Segment(start, end)
        return super().__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self,
                 start: int,
                 end: int,
                 *,
                 start_inclusive: bool,
                 end_inclusive: bool) -> None:
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        self.start_inclusive = start_inclusive
        self.end_inclusive = end_inclusive

class Segment(Interval):
    def __new__(cls, start: int, end: int) -> 'Interval':
        return super().__new__(cls, start, end,
                               start_inclusive=True,
                               end_inclusive=True)

    def __init__(self, start: int, end: int) -> None:
        super().__init__(start, end,
                         start_inclusive=True,
                         end_inclusive=True)

print(Interval(0, 1, start_inclusive=True, end_inclusive=True))
# <__main__.Segment object at ...>
```